# Fix error : "Your push failed because you've exceeded your user limit which is shown in bitbucket"

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

```
********************************************************************************
[ALERT] Your push failed because you've exceeded your user limit, and this
[ALERT] repository is restricted to read-only access.
[ALERT] Change your plan to restore write access:
[ALERT] https://bitbucket.org/account/user/dsasaas/plans
********************************************************************************
```

Finally I found the issue it  occurs  if your workspace settings has more than 5 users.

Follow this step  to solve the issue

1. Goto Bitbucket
2. Open  Settings(Which is in the top left side)
3. Then goto the User directory which is under Access management
4. Remove Workspace user if it exceeds more than 5  user
5. Finally I follow the procedures and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I have had 8 users (including myself) on my workspace for *months*, and am only just now getting this error...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I got this error today too, I followed your steps and it fixed it.